# Interpretation of VARselect() results

Tags: r

I read this post ([Selecting an appropriate lag for a regression equation and how to interpret the results of VARselect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14131676/selecting-an-appropriate-lag-for-a-regression-equation-and-how-to-interpret-the)), covering the similar basics of my question already, but still am not sure about how to exactly interpret the results.

My dataset (VARTotal_df) contains 14 economic and financial variables with 121 obs. each) My VARselect() results are in particular:

```
VARselect(VARTotal_df,lag.max=10,type="none") # AIC, HQ, SC and FPEsuggest lag of 8
$selection
AIC(n)  HQ(n)  SC(n) FPE(n) 
     8      8      8      7 

$criteria
                  1            2            3            4            5            6            7    8    9   10
AIC(n) 6.380974e+01 6.430259e+01 6.484109e+01 6.410062e+01 6.204580e+01 5.739413e+01          NaN -Inf -Inf -Inf
HQ(n)  6.575063e+01 6.818436e+01 7.066375e+01 7.186418e+01 7.175024e+01 6.903945e+01          NaN -Inf -Inf -Inf
SC(n)  6.859414e+01 7.387138e+01 7.919428e+01 8.323821e+01 8.596778e+01 8.610050e+01          NaN -Inf -Inf -Inf
FPE(n) 5.253281e+27 9.861064e+27 2.516204e+28 2.861553e+28 2.023257e+28 5.558990e+27 -51057843500    0    0    0

Warning messages:
1: In log(sigma.det) : NaNs produced
2: In log(sigma.det) : NaNs produced
3: In log(sigma.det) : NaNs produced
```

Apparently, a lag of 8 is most appropriate. However, I am wondering whether this can be used as lag 7 contain NaN's and the lags 8 to 10 -Inf's.

Clarification from a more knowledgeable person would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I know this answer may come a little late, but in case it can still help you or someone else out there, here's why you got `-Inf` for lags 8 and greater:

Let *L* equal the number of lags and *D* equal the number of endogenous variables for your VAR, and *N* equal the number of observations in your dataset. Then your VAR will have *DL* explanatory variables and *N - L* number of observations. If *DL > N - L*, some of your variables' coefficients cannot be estimated by OLS.

So, in your case, *D* = 14 and *N* = 121. If *L* is greater than or equal to 8, *DL >  N - L* since *DL* = 112 and *N - L* = 107 when *L* = 8. Essentially, you do not have enough observations in your dataset to calculate the criteria for lags 8 or greater.

Comment: Your logic doesn't hold up in my use case. I have the same issue as the op. My parameters are as followed: L = 2, D = 2, n = 115. Can you cite your reference? Thanks.

Comment: @Starbucks The calculations were my own. Note they do not account for any exogenous variables. If you include *p* exogenous variables then you have *DL* + *p* explanatory variables. Are you using `VARselect()` and getting `-Inf` for `AIC`, `HQ`, and `SC` for some lags? If so, you may have gotten this result for an entirely different reason than the OP. I would suggest posting a new question.